# Proof verification: linear span is the smallest subspace containing vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I've already read several answers to this very same question. Although I understand the proof, I came up with one slightly different (and shorter I think) for the smallest subspace part, and I'd like to be sure it has no gaps. Since I want to focus on the smallest subspace part, I left out the proof that the span is a subspace (which is not very difficult).

**Proposition.** The linear span of a list of vectors in $V$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing all the vectors in the list.

*Proof.* Suppose $v_1,\dots,v_m$ is a list of vectors in $V$. Let $S=\text{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_m)$.

[proof that span is subspace left out]

Let $T$ be an arbitrary subspace of $V$. Suppose $v_1,\ldots,v_m \in T$. To show $S \subseteq T$, take some vector $w \in S$. Then, there exists scalars $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m$ such that
$$w=\alpha_1v_1+\ldots+\alpha_mv_m.$$
Setting a $\alpha_j=1$ and $\alpha_i=0$ for all $i \neq j$, we have that $w=v_j$. Since $T$ contains $v_j$, then $w \in T$. Therefore, $S \subseteq T$, as desired. **QED**

I read that some people prove that $S$ contains $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ and that it is smallest separately. For the former, the argument is the one I used above, whereas for the latter they use the fact that $T$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, and, therefore, $T$ contains all linear combinations of the list of vectors. Because of this, I felt I might have a flaw in my proof.

Does my proof have any gaps? Does the way I wrote prove $S$ contains the vectors AND is the smallest subspace containing these?

Comment: What do you mean by "setting" a $v_j=1$ and $v_i=0$? The $v_i$'s are vectors not scalars. In case you meant $\alpha_j=1$ and $\alpha_i=0$, then too the problem is that you do not have a control over the $\alpha_k$'s (the sentence before that says, $\exists$ scalars....), so you don't have the freedom to choose them at will.

Comment: If $w$ is taken arbitrary, why do you choose it to be $w=v_j$? In this case, it is obvious that $w\in T$, because $v_j$ is already in $T$.

Comment: You should edit your post to say what you mean by "span".  Personally, I'd have said that the definition was "the smallest linear space containing the given set", see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) for instance.  Of course, using that definition makes the problem trivial.  I assume you mean, instead, the collection of finite linear combinations made from the given set, but you should say so.

Comment: @AnuragA You are right, I already corrected the typo. And yes, I see now that what I did does not make any sense at all, very silly mistake.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I meant linear span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect. In order to show that $S\subseteq T$ you need to prove that **for any** $w\in S$ you have $w\in T$. So you cannot set $v_j=1$ and $v_i=0$. It does not make sense, and you cannot have any constraint on the $\alpha_i$'s. (I guess this is what you meant)

Here you basically said :  Assume that $v_i$ is in T, then $v_i$ is in T. That's it.

**Edit :** the correct argument goes as:

- Assume $w\in S$.
- By definition of $S$ as linear span, there exist $\alpha_i$'s
  such that $w=\alpha_1v_1+\ldots, \alpha_mv_m$.
- By Assumption, $T$ contains all $v_i$'s.
- As $T$ is a vector space, it is closed under vector addition and scalar
  multiplication, i.e. $\alpha_1v_1+\ldots, \alpha_mv_m \in T$
- Therefore $w\in T$ and $S\subseteq T$

As $T$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing all $v_i$'s, and $S$ is a subspace of $V$ containing all $v_i$'s with $S\subseteq T$, then $T=S$.

Comment: My God, very silly mistake of mine. Thank you for the clarification. Then, I guess I could conclude that $w \in S$ using the fact that $\alpha_1v_1+\ldots+\alpha_mv_m \in T$ because $T$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, right? Is it necessary to prove that $S$ contains $v_1,\ldots,v_m$?

Comment: @LucasPeres I have update the answer with an outline of the argument.